# How do I "Dockerise" a client/server setup using socket.io?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Forgive the vague question title, I'm a complete beginner and I lack the terminology to pose my question more specifically.

I've been developing a simple application that consists of a game server (using socket.io, so WebSockets) and a game client, which is just an HTTP server. I've finished developing locally and would now like to host it on the servers of my student organisation; seeing as that machine already has Docker installed I figured that would be the easiest solution.

Concretely, in local development I've set the WebSockets server to use port 3141 and the HTTP server to use port 5173. I tried my hand at using `docker compose` and came up with the following configuration:

```yaml
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3141
  frontend:
    build: ./kwispel-client
    ports:
      - 5173
```

Using `docker inspect kwispel-server-server-1` I can then manually figure out the IP address of the HTTP server and connect to it. However, container naming resolution doesn't work; I need that for

- telling the client side of socket.io where to connect to, and passing in `http://server:3141` doesn't work;
- telling the server side of socket.io which CORS headers to allow, and passing in `http://frontend:5173` doesn't work
  Locally the project works fine using `localhost` instead of `server` or `frontend`.

If I try defining a shared network, like such:

```yaml
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3141
    networks:
      kwispel-server_gedeeldNetwerk:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10  
  frontend:
    build: ./kwispel-client
    ports:
      - 5173
    networks:
      kwispel-server_gedeeldNetwerk:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.20
networks:
  kwispel-server_gedeeldNetwerk:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.16.238.0/24"
```

so that I can have fixed IP addresses, I can't even connect to the HTTP server on that address.

Am I missing something obvious? Do I need to pass an extra flag to `docker-compose up` to expose the ports I need? I'm at a complete loss. Any pointers in the right direction are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a `Dockerfile` to build your image. What I like to do is build the image, first, then reference that image in `docker-compose.yml` such that I am only using docker-compose for running the containers.

Here is a good tutorial with an example of a `Dockerfile` that can help:
https://dockerize.io/guides/node-socket-giude

Also, have a look at existing Docker images that have socket.io support:
https://hub.docker.com/search?q=socket.io